# Does every Rails request instantiate new Helper modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, puma, actioncontroller

I know every request to a Rails app instantiates a new controller for the request, so the controller itself is thread safe.

So, if I make a request to `/users`, the `UsersController` for example will be a new instance.

However, `UsersController` inherits from `ApplicationController` and my `ApplicationController` is something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def authenticate_user!
    # example
  end

  include CurrentUserHelper
end
```

This is my CurrentUserHelper:

```
module CurrentUserHelper
  def current_user
    return @current_user if @current_user

    @current_user = #logic to set current user
  end

  class UserNotFound < StandardError
  end
end
```

Since I use an instance variable in the `CurrentUserHelper` I'm not sure if it is thread safe since I don't know if it is a new instance of the module for every request. I ask because my web server is `Puma` and I want multiple threads.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm overthinking this... it should be okay as module is included in the new instance of the class and the instance variable will be applied to the class.